# Finding areas within a region using postgis or google api

Tags: postgresql, google-api, geolocation, postgis

I have a location table that have more than million records. If that location is a **region** the ticket isRegion is marked true for it

All the records have their longitude and latitude values stored

I want to find the areas that fall in a particular region

Is there a way to achieve this using postgis or google api?

**EDIT**

I don't have the area data of the location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes PostGIS can handle those operations without a problem, just transform your long lat data to geometry

1. Add a geometry column to your table

   alter table schema.table add column geom geometry(point, 4326);

2.Create geometry for your point

```
select ('SRID=4326;POINT('||long ||' '||lat ||')')::geometry
from table; /*just to test*/

update schema.table set geom= ('SRID=4326;POINT('||long ||' '||lat ||')')::geometry 
where lat is not null and long is not null; /*save to your table*/
```

If your database has no activated postgis extension do

```
create extension postgis;
```

and use polygons https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Polygon.html to define your areas of interest, then use ST_Contains function to know if geometry B(points) is completely inside geometry A (polygon), as shown in official docs https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html

Comment: the long lat values are already in point. But i don't have the data about area. and I can't define area of 1 million records manually. is there an api that provides data about a locations area?

Comment: There are public cartography or you could draw your areas of interest using QGIS. More info on this subjects in https://gis.stackexchange.com/